# How to encrypt Viewstate properly in asp.net webform

Tags: asp.net, encryption, webforms, viewstate

I am using asp.net webform website which is using 4.5 framework and vunrability scanner show viewstate as `Unencrypted __VIEWSTATE parameter`

Even though i am using machine key it still flags it

```
 <machineKey validationKey="xxxxxxxxxxxx" decryptionKey="xxxxxxxxxxxx" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
```

Is this how viewstate can be encrypted in asp.net webform 4.5

Answer (score 5):

You can set the ViewState encryption in the `pages` node under `system.web` of the Web.Config.

```
<system.web>  
  <pages viewStateEncryptionMode="Always" />  
</system.web>
```

More info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.page.viewstateencryptionmode?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Web_UI_Page_ViewStateEncryptionMode

Comment: I did this so many times also also it generates server error when i use `<pages viewStateEncryptionMode="Always" />` error for me & i noticed that i was using `pages` tag for something else. No now i modified it to look `<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" viewStateEncryptionMode="Always">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>`

Comment: I hope the way i have added it is correct otherwise i will add it at page level